# When swiping to delete UITableViewCell red minus sign delete icon shows up occasionally

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitableview

I'm working on a app that has a UITableView that uses custom UITableViewCells. When you swipe one of the rows the delete confirmation button shows up and works fine. Also when you hit my "edit" button the rows indent showing the minus sign icon and everything works as well. However after leaving the editing mode and then doing a swipe delete, the minus sign icon and the delete confirmation button both show up without indenting the row. After changing the view and coming back, the swipe works fine as it did before.

How do I make it so that the minus sign does not ever show up when swiping to delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you override the UITableViewCell's didTransitionToState method without calling the parent's method. Just try to add the following line in your didTransitionToState:

```
[super didTransitionToState:state];
```